# Does this public get set for a private variable make sense?

Tags: c#, getter-setter

I am working on a codebase a student with questionable knowledge made, here I am just confused if there is any reasonable intend there or if its just unnecessary... I personally would just use the ShowNewButton field and trash the _showNewBtn, please provide an opinion.

```
private _showNewBtn;
public bool ShowNewButton
        {
            get => _showNewBtn;
            set
            {
                bbNew.Visibility = value == false ? BarItemVisibility.Never : BarItemVisibility.Always;

                _showNewBtn = value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The intent here is to show or hide a control based on this property. There are probably better ways of binding the UI display to the model, but this is the right way of attaching code to a property. "student with questionable knowledge" is not very nice of you, btw.

Comment: Its encapsulation. You wouldn't/shouldn't normally expose a field. But also because there is additional logic in the setter (setting the visibility) there's generally no real way around it (outside of any property binding techniques the UI may offer, of course)

Comment: @Kobi I know but I have seen things here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no reason (in the sample you provided) for the `_showNewBtn`.
You now have 2 markers which contain the visibility state of the button. At some point, this will cause problems if you aren't carefull.
Either remove the `_showNewBtn` completely:

```
public bool ShowNewButton
{
  get => bbNew.Visibility == BarItemVisibility.Always;
  set
  {
    bbNew.Visibility = value == false ? BarItemVisibility.Never : BarItemVisibility.Always;
  }
}
```

Or justify the existance of `_showNewBtn` which makes my remark null and void.